# Differentiation of an implicit function

Tags: implicit-differentiation

$$ x = y^x $$

been working through some implicit functions and this has me a bit, I don't think my answer is correct

I have treated $y$ as $y(x)^x$ and differentiated with respect to x

Comment: What answer have you gotten? Your last line seems to be the right way to think about the problem based on the information you've given.

Comment: Take natural log of both sides, use algebra, differentiate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
F(x,y) = y^x - x = 0.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{\partial F/\partial x}{\partial F/\partial y} = -\frac{y^x \ln y - 1}{xy^{x-1}}
$$
We can simplify this: $y^x = x$, and
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x\ln y - 1}{x^2 / y} = \frac{y}{x^2} - \frac{y\ln y}{x}
$$
We can take $\log$:
$$
x\ln y = \ln x\Longrightarrow \ln y = \frac{\ln x}{x}\tag1
$$
So,
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x^2}(1-\ln x)
$$

Or, we may follow @Mattos and differentiate $(1)$ directly.

There is another way. We know that
$$
y = x^{1/x} = e^{\ln x/x}.
$$
So,
$$
y ' = x^{1/x} \Big(\frac{\ln x}{x}\Big)' = x^{1/x}\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2} = \frac{y}{x^2} (1-\ln x).
$$